# Make disappear image on the edge of rectangle

Tags: actionscript-3

I have to move some pictures in my flash. So I have got a background image in my main MovieClip(which I get by Loader class). Inside the image I have rectangles. I'm going to put small image in this rectangle and move it.  I need the small image slowly disappear while crossing the rectangle boundaries.
I tried to put another movieclip in rectangles and moved image in this movieclip. But while crossing the rectangle the image didnt disappear. The image just continued its motion without disappearing.
How can I make dissapearing of image while crossing rectangle boundaries?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/).  It's an animation "tweening" library that makes animation a breeze.  There are others, but this is the one I use.
2. It depends on the methodology you employ to move and detect your overlaps of image & rectangles.

Let's imagine you have two squares (red square, and blue square) and you want red square to fade-out whenever it overlaps blue square.  Is this controlled with the mouse, keyboard, or a pre-calculated move that performs a guaranteed eclipse?  Is the fade a factor of the percentage of overlap, or a straight-up 0-to-100 timed transition the moment it comes in contact with blue square?  It's not clear from the description you gave as to what exactly you expect your code to do.  Please review [SO's "Asking" section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to help improve the quality of your question so that you get the right answer you're looking for.

That said, here's one way you could resolve the issue:

```
import com.greensock.*;

// Create some sample red & blue squares
var red:Sprite = new Sprite();
red.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
red.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
red.graphics.endFill();

addChild(red);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateRed);

var blue:Sprite = new Sprite();
blue.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1);
blue.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
blue.graphics.endFill();
addChild(blue);
blue.x = 200;
blue.y = 100;

var overlap:Boolean = false; // global state tracker

function updateRed(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Position the red square every time the mouse moves
    red.x = stage.mouseX - red.width/2; // center relative to red square's dimensions
    red.y = stage.mouseY - red.height/2;

    if (red.hitTestObject(blue) && overlap != true) {
        // Make sure we only animate on the initial overlap
        overlap = true;
        TweenLite.to(red, 1, {alpha:0});
    } else if (red.hitTestObject(blue) == false && overlap) {
        // And converserly, on the initial exit
        overlap = false;
        TweenLite.to(red, 1, {alpha:1});
    }
}
```

Comment: I need  red square disappear slowly from 1-100 percentage while crossing the blue square. I dont want it disappear immediately 100% after crossing another square.